# Can firebase facedetection used for authentication

Tags: firebase-mlkit

I want to use Firebase Face detection in Android.
As far as I read, it can detect faces.
Can I save the detected face and compare it next time for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at the moment, [ML Kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/detect-faces) only does face detection, and gives you face landmark coordinates. It will be a very inaccurate method if used for face authentication.

Comment: Can I save the face detected as jpg/png or bitmp?

Comment: Definitely. The ML Kit will give you the coordinates of the face detected. So you can certainly crop out the detected part from the the bitmap.